# EditText in RecyclerView causes scroll to jump around

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have an `EditText` inside a `RecyclerView`. Whenever I press any key on the keyboard, the RecyclerView scroll jumps around.

At first I thought it might be that the list is constantly updating on every key stroke, but that is not the case. I only update the list items once.

Please don't suggest using `adjustPan`. Yes, that will solve the problem in portrait, since the list isn't very long, but the problem still occurs on small screens or in landscape mode when the list doesn't fit on screen.

I've also tested with and without `nestedScrollingEnabled="false"`, which didn't help either.

Here's a GIF showing what's happening. In this case I'm just pressing the backspace key over and over again.

What is causing this, and how do I prevent it?

[image]

Comment: could you paste your code